# OSX 10.7.4 samba3.6.6 get_user_groups: failed to get the unix group list

Tags: mac-osx, samba

Hello I've been running samba3 via mac ports on osx for quite sometime.  I don't use it very often but recently I noticed I could no longer login.  I know I've done system updates to osx, but now I get some weird error when trying to start it.

```
osx:~ rick$ sudo /opt/local/sbin/smbd -i
smbd version 3.6.6 started.
Copyright Andrew Tridgell and the Samba Team 1992-2011
get_user_groups: failed to get the unix group list
create_local_token failed: NT_STATUS_NO_SUCH_USER
osx:~ rick$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into the same issue recently.  It seems to be a problem that's already known for a long time, but haven't been fixed in mac ports yet.

The problem is that the root user is in more than 64 groups (which seems to be some kind of a hard limit), which is causing problems.

I'm using Samba 3.6.5 from Homebrew on Montain Lion and it's working fine for me.

There has been a lot of discussion about this issue here:
https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/5954